# GTA V for PC exited unexpectedly

Tags: pc, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I recently ordered the GTA V PC from Steam and when I finished installing and launch the game. It gave me "Grand Theft Auto V has exited unexpectedly". I tried "safe mod" and every option available, but none of them work. I checked some forums and found a lot of people having the same problems. What could be the possible cause? I'm using a laptop with these specs:

CPU: i7 4700m
GPU: AMD HD8970M
RAM: 8GB

I'm pretty sure my laptop is way beyond the minimum specs. Does someone know how can I enter the game?

Comment: have you tried running the game as administrator?

Comment: Apparently, if your Windows user name contains any special characters (such as é or ä or ç, etc.) then the game might fail to start. I'm guessing GTA 5 is trying to write config files or save files in your personal folder, but handles Unicode characters improperly. If your user name contains even one such character, you'll have to wait for a patch.

Comment: I understand this problem. My user name are purely upper English letters. I did try to run the game as administrator. But it required me to launch through Steam. And I didn't even find the file named "PlayGTAV.exe" in the file directory.

Comment: I completely read this as "GTA V for PC excited unexpectedly" and was expecting to see lots of "this is off topics"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The launcher is broken on laptops with graphics switching technologies, so until there's a patch or something, the launcher will crash every time you try to launch it with both gpu's enabled.

A temporary workaround is to go to Device manager, disable your dedicated gpu (in your case - AMD), launch the game and while the launcher is showing "Loading" enable your gpu back again. This will prevent launcher from crashing, while still allowing you to run the game with your dedicated gpu. If you don't get it right on first try, try re-enabling the gpu slightly later, timing is the key here.
You have to do this every time you launch the game, except when restarting from within the game to apply graphics settings.

[I made a video that shows when to re-enable the gpu](https://youtu.be/o8BMGwDIihY)

Edit: The latest update (17-04-15) fixed the issue and workaround isn't needed anymore
Edit2: The update seems to have not fixed the issue for everyone, especially AMD users.

Comment: I have to use this workaround myself, as my main gaming rig is a laptop as well.

Comment: I tried this method and when the launcher show up it says:"failed to initialize DX 9 device".

Comment: Your timing must have been off, I believe. Try enabling gpu slightly earlier. If it crashes, you enabled it too early, if it throws any initialization error, you did it too late. It took me a couple tries to get it working myself, so don't lose hope if it doesn't work on first couple attempts, after you find the right timing, you should be able to get it running every time.
There is a slight chance that it might not work with AMD gpu's (I have an nvidia gpu,so I can't test), in which case you can either only play with the intel gpu (disable amd and run the game) or wait until a proper fix :(

Comment: I think this might have something related to AMD GPU. After I disabled my dedicated GPU and launch the game through Steam it didn't even give me enough time to enable it again. As soon as I opened it gave me"unable to initialize DirectX 9 device".

Comment: It finally worked, the timing is really crucial. I don't understand why Rockstar doesn't support graphic card switching since today lots of laptops already support this technology.

Comment: I'm sure they will support it, it's just something they, for some reason, didn't think of or assumed it would work and didn't test for it. Hopefully, within a week or less, it will be resolved officially, but until then, we have to rely on workarounds like this.

Comment: The latest update didn't fix the issue in all cases.

Comment: The solution has been posted in the following section. It works for me at least. After the loading screen disappeared double click the hotfix exe file and wait it to receive error code and the game will launch in about 1 minute or so. I use the older version hotfix though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hot fox for my laptops, it doesn't provided permanent fix but it can let you play the game using your dedicated GPU. (It might only work for laptops with intel CPU and AMD GPU for laptops)

It solves my problem of getting "GTA V.exe exited unexpectedly". After the loading windows disappeared just open the software and wait for about a minute depend on your machine.