# Grand Theft Auto V has exited unexpectedly

Tags: pc, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I have a Sager NP9150 laptop with an i7-3610QM CPU and a AMD HD 7970m GPU. I get the Grand Theft Auto V has exited unexpectedly  error when I try run the game and it happens in safe mode also. It was mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213997/gta-v-for-pc-exited-unexpectedly) how someone else got it working. I tried following those steps but could not get it working. Does anyone know any workaround for laptops with an AMD GPU?

Comment: Yes the software still has some technical issues on PC. I'm sure that Rockstar will fix it soon. Are there any logfiles or crash reports you could show us?

Comment: There are no options that show up that would allow me to get log files. Is it somewhere in GTAV directory, where I could access these files?

Comment: does [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/32i41z) helps you?

Comment: The only thing that works is if i disable the dedicated graphics card and just run it only on integrated. If I try to re-enable the card, it will crash.